# Gradle authentication - could not get unknown property 'artifactoryUsername' for Credentials

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I get following error when trying to build with gradle:

Could not get unknown property 'artifactoryUsername' for Credentials [username: null] of type org.gradle.internal.credentials.DefaultPasswordCredentials_Decorated.

I have my credentials stored in gradle.properties file in ~/.gradle folder.

Comment: Do you really mean `~/.docker`, or do you mean `~/.gradle`?